# Whats a good solvent to analyze amygdalin in FTIR?

Tags: organic-chemistry, solvents, ir-spectroscopy

What solvents would be good to analyze [amygdalin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amygdalin) using FTIR spectroscopy? Will carbon tetrachloride react with the amygdalin if used as a solvent?

Comment: KBr disc is the standard method. Why complicate it with solvents/liquid phase spectra? It is a sugar, will it dissolve in carbon tetrachloride? Think about it.

Comment: If you aim for a quick substance identification, why not opt-in for [ATR-FTIR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attenuated_total_reflectance) to record the data of the neat substance? Then, there is no need to identify a suitable solvent. Then, the solvent does not influence the position of the absorption bands and there aren't absorption bands of the solvent to account and correct for. But you should apply (and note in the report) a correction for the wavelength dependent dispersion/penetration depth between your window (Si, Ge, diamond) and sample -- check the spectrometer software for this.